# How do I correctly verify mongodb sessions?

Tags: mongodb, authentication, session, middleware, mern

I'm building a mern small app from scratch, I'm currently on the last step of authentication and I want to manage user sessions in my mongodb. How can I program the middleware or should I move to passport.js. I wanted to implement this myself for personal growth but at the same time I want a app that works. I can't find any tutorials relating to my design style, where can I look for more documentation?

My current coding experience is one year self-taught so forgive the spaghetti or nasty logic I plan to refactor soon.

**Current code**

```
#config
const Users = require('../models/users');
const User = require('../models/user');

#verification logic
async function getUserSession(req, res) {
  try {
    let subscriber = await Users.findOne();
    
    const inputString = subscriber;

    // Clean up the string by removing extra characters
    const cleanedString = inputString.replace(/'/g, '').replace(/\\"/g, '"');

    const parsedObject = JSON.parse(cleanedString);

    // Extract the userId
    const userId = "'" + parsedObject.userId + "'";
    let correctSubscriber = await User.findById(userId);
    
    if (!correctSubscriber) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid user' });
    }

    console.log(userId);
    // Do something with the user data if needed

    // Send a success response if everything is fine
    return res.status(200).json({ message: 'User found successfully' });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
  }
}


#main middleware function
async function authenticateLogin(req, res, next) {

  let subscriberCheck = getUserSession;

  if(subscriberCheck) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(401).send(`<h1>Sorry, login in first</h1>`);
  }
}
```

**previously I split them but I think programmed the javascript incorrectly

preivious attempt**

```
const Users = require('../models/users');
const User = require('../models/user');

async function authenticateLogin(req, res, next) {
  let subscriber = getUserSession;
  let subscriberCheck = getCorrectUser;

  if(subscriber === subscriberCheck) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(401).send(`<h1>Sorry, login in first</h1>`);
  }
}

async function getUserSession(req, res) {
  let subscriber = await Users.findOne()
  
  const inputString = subscriber;

  // Clean up the string by removing extra characters
  const cleanedString = inputString.replace(/'/g, '').replace(/\\"/g, '"');

  try {

    const parsedObject = JSON.parse(cleanedString);

    // Extract the userId
    const userId = "'" + parsedObject.userId + "'";
    
    console.log(userId);
    return userId;
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(inputString)
      return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message})
  }
}


async function getCorrectUser ( req, res, next, getUserSession){

  let subscriber = await User.findById(getUserSessionuser)
  
  try {


    const userId = subscriber;
    console.log(userId);
    return subscriber;

    
  } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(err.message);
  }
  
 
  next();
}
```